# How will an expression be stored on the stack?

Tags: c++

How will an expression like `2*4+6-3/2` be stored on the stack?

Comment: The compiler can replace it with a constant. Probably that is not what you want to know.

Comment: Do you want the answer? or the way the compiler uses stacks to evaluate the expression?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER, I personally would like to know the latter. Would you mind to post a link for that?

Comment: Would you rather know how it is evaluated (as there is nothing to really store on the stack) (no variable no stack member).

Answer (score 4):

Your C++ compiler will store this: `13`.

And then the format in which it will be stored is determined by usage. Assigning it to a `float` makes the compiler store it different than when assigned to an `int`. I don't doubt the compiler changes `((float) 2*4+6-3/2)` to `13.0f`.

Answer (score 3):

It won't unless you store it in a variable, i.e. `int a = 2*4+6-3/2`

A local variable occupies space on the stack, which is taken care of by the compiler. Basically, upon entering a function, a new stack frame is chopped off from the stack memory. Within this 'frame', local variables (amongst other information) are stored.

Comment: The compiler will compile this as `int a = 13` anyway. The calculation itself is never stored anyway, which is the entire point of this question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you mean exactly this, but : there is a notation that is very useful when it comes to calculate expressions using a stack, its Reverse Polish Notation.

Here's a link to more information and the implementation :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Answer (score 1):

The expression will not be stored on the stack. The compiler will put the result of this in .const segment.

When you are inside a function and have

```
float foo = 2*4+6-3/2; // floating point
int foo = 2*4+6-3/2; // int
```

will assign (or cast if need) that var in .const section to your variable that is on stack.

Answer (score 0):

The expression will not be stored anywhere, but the result will be. How it is stored depends on how you use it:

```
float foo = 2*4+6-3/2; // store result as floating point
int foo = 2*4+6-3/2; // store result as int
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that `2*4+6-3/2` will be stored on the "stack" in standard C++ is like:

```
#include <stack>

int main()
{
   std::stack<int> s;
   s.push(2*4+6-3/2);
}
```

The value 13 is stored in the stack.

Now if, as I suspect, you were not in fact referring to stack but to *statically-allocated objects* (don't forget, C++ doesn't care where they go physically), then you should consider that "2*4+6-3/2" is an rvalue (a *temporary*, in this case). Only when assigned to a variable will storage take place. And then, the literals will be evaluated to produce the single value "13". The mathematical expression will not be kept.